# form always submit get mothod

Tags: php

this is my form, i have a problem that when i submit this form, method is alway get althought i set method is post. when i set method is get then it don't sent parameters and in url not have parameters and value. anybody can help me resolve this problem.i have use **froala editor**(is this problem?) thanks very much

```
<form action="./create" method="post" id="createblog">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title"  placeholder="Tiltle" name="title" value="" style="width:30%">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="cate" name="cate" style="width:30%">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($rs as $item){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $item['cat_id']?>"><?php echo $item['cat_name'];}?></option>;
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="100" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" formaction="./create" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: typographic error. The code says `get` the question says it is set to `post`.

Answer (score 0):

You show quite clearly in your code that you are in fact specifying GET as the method, not POST.

form action="./create" **method="get"** id="createblog"

Comment: i have a problem when i set method is " post" but when i submit it alway is "get" . i will edit my question. thanks